# Executing ruby script with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with running ruby script in spring framework.

Let's say I have a script named 'my_script.rb', when I run it from terminal it works perfectly normal. When I execute it in "normal" java program:

```
 public class RubyExecutor {

 public static String execute(String command){
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append("\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
}


    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(RubtExecutor.execute("ruby /home/wookash/script.rb \"/home/wookash/rubyScripts\" \"case_0/\""));
}
```

script still works.
Problem comes when I put mentioned-above code in spring app.
What is weird: literally half of ruby script runs, magicly second half of lines of code is not being executed, no matter what is there. No errors, no warnings, nothing. I'm guessing that is caused by Spring task execution framework. However i have no idea how to fix it. Thank You in advance.

//EDIT I am pasting my spring method.

```
@RequestMapping("/execute")
    public void executeCmd(){
            executeCommand("ruby /home/wookash/script.rb \"/home/wookash/rubyScripts\" \"case_0/\"");
    }
    private String executeCommand(String command) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
```

Comment: You're not even showing any Spring-related code.

Comment: @kryger But my Spring code is exactly the same like "reguar" java code (but ofcourse without main function). This is whole problem. When i run it from console as regular java program, ruby script run, but when i run it with spring, it doesn't.